# Code First EF6 - Update Many-To-Many Relationship in MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, repository, entity-framework-6

I have a many to many relationship between Courses and Ingredients, and a one-to-many relationship between Meals and Courses.

```
public MealContext _context = new MealContext();
public IEnumerable<Meal> Meals { get { return  _context.Meals.Include("Courses"); } }
public IEnumerable<Course> Courses { get { return   _context.Courses.Include("Ingredients"); } }
public IEnumerable<Ingredient> Ingredients { get { return _context.Ingredients; }

public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}

public class Meal : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public Meal Meal { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Ingredients")]
    public List<int> IngredientIds { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public bool AddMeal(ref Meal meal)
{
    try
    {
        _context.Meals.Add(meal);
        foreach (var course in meal.Courses)
        {
            course.Created = DateTime.Now;
            course.Updated = DateTime.Now;

            _context.Courses.Add(course);
            if(course.Ingredients == null) { course.Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>(); }
            foreach (var ingredient in course.Ingredients)
            {
                _context.Entry(ingredient).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        meal.Created = DateTime.Now;
        meal.Updated = DateTime.Now;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        trans.Commit();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Error(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        trans.Rollback();
        return false;
    }
}
```

On the meal create view, I can add courses to a meal, and add ingredients to a course.  Everything works as intended.

However, when I attempt to edit a meal, none of the ingredient changes to courses are ever saved, and no exception is thrown.

My view uses drop down lists generated in an editor template to populate the IngredientIds collection, and I have verified that the list is both populated and correct by the time it reaches my repository.

I've tried loading each course object from the database, setting each value of the tracked object to the value of the untracked object using _context.Entry(dbCourse).CurrentValues.SetValues(course).

I've tried loading the ingredients into a list from the database by Id (course.Ingredients = _context.Ingredients.Where(i => course.IngredientIds.Contains(i.Id));).

I've tried flagging each ingredient using _context.Entry(ingredient).State = EntityState.Modified.

Nothing I do seems to work, and I've gone through just about every StackOverflow post I can find on the topic (most of which boil down to one of the three solutions above).

How do I get these relationships to save properly?

Currently, my update function looks like this:

```
public bool UpdateMeal(ref Meal meal)
{
    using (var trans = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            meal.Updated = DateTime.Now;
            if (meal.Courses != null)
            {
                foreach (var course in meal.Courses)
                {
                    course.Updated = DateTime.Now;
                    if (course.IngredientIds != null && course.IngredientIds.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var newIngredients = _context.Ingredients.Where(i => course.IngredientIds.Contains(i.Id)).ToList();
                        course.Ingredients = newIngredients;
                    }
                    var dbCourse = _context.Courses.Include("Ingredients").Single(c => c.Id == course.Id);
                    _context.Entry(dbCourse).CurrentValues.SetValues(course);
                }
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
            trans.Commit();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            trans.Rollback();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Course needs a `virtual ICollection<Ingredient>`and Ingredient needs a `virtual ICollection<Course>`. EF should create a join table called either IngredientCourses or CourseIngredients. I did a quick test model

```
public class Meal
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }

    public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int MealId { get; set; }
        public virtual Meal Meal{ get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
    }

    public class Ingredient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    }
```

and created a new meal....

```
    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = new MealContext())
        {
            var meal = new Model.Meal();
            var course = new Model.Course();
            var ingredient = new Model.Ingredient();
            var ingredient2 = new Model.Ingredient();
            course.Ingredients = new[] { ingredient, ingredient2 };
            meal.Courses = new[] { course };
            context.Meals.Add(meal);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

and ended up with [image]

Comment: EF6 already creates the database tables properly, and I can save new Meals.  It's when I go to edit an existing meal that the relationships between courses and ingredients aren't saved.

Comment: After separating the entity into a data model and a view model, this approach worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would help to change the navigation properties to `virtual` so that Entity Framework can create a lazy loading proxy.

Example:

```
public virtual List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
public virtual Meal Meal { get; set; }
```

And you might need to tell EF about your relations. To do so, add the flowing method to your DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // One to many
    modelBuilder.Entity<Meal>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Courses)
        .WithRequired(x => x.Meal);

    // Many to many
    modelBuilder.Entity<Course>()
        .HasMany(x => x.Ingredients)
        .WithMany();
}
```

Comment: I udated the post to show my current implementation of the update function.  I use include statements, which I thought made virtual navigation properties for lazy loading unnecessary.


I'll try adding the method to my DbContext.  I figured that part was unnecessary as well, since EF was able to create the tables without it, and the AddMeal function worked.

Comment: EF will do a lot by convention but it's safer to explicitly define your relations using the model builder. Yes you could skip the virtual keywords but if you forget an include the property will be null and you will spend extra time debugging. Again, it's not required but it helps.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, unfortunately that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: It's your `UpdateMeal()`. That method is really hard to understand...you are really over-complicating things. You don't need a list of Ids you just add the ingredient object to the list like Carmine's answer.

Comment: Right now the Ids property exists because the items are selected from a listbox.  The listbox just populates the Ids collection, which then populates the ingredients collection.  I'll try separating it out using a view model to see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Yes, your classes used by EF should only contain stuff that is mapped to the database.

Comment: That worked.  Once I separated the data model and the view model, Carmine's answer worked.

Comment: Good, I guess mine would have worked too, it's just that by defining a List<> on each side (like Carmine) EF is able to guess (by convention) your Many-To-Many relation. Since at first you did not have a List<> on the other side (in the Ingredients class) you would need to tell explicitly EF that it's a many-to-many with the modelBuilder. I hope you understand ^_^